# How to tell whether the palm of the hand is facing up or down using Bone Orientation with Kinect for Windows SDK

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

Is it possible to tell whether the palm of the hand is facing up or down using Bone Orientation with the Kinect for Windows SDK?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it is... I've seen a game where you have to puppeteer a character, and it does check for the position of your hand. Waiting for a code example or explanation, though.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the Microsoft SDK as it only tracks the joints at wrist and hand - you need a third point (e.g. a thumb) to get the cross product. I think you will need to use a third party library with OpenNI such as this http://cvrlcode.ics.forth.gr/handtracking/

Answer (score 0):

No, You cannot.
The Bone Orientation is the rotation of the physical bones in the 3D space. It cannot calculate a wrist twist for example. But can calculate the rotations of your hand when you wave your hand (Ex:-saying Ta Ta to someone).